# Is using fold less efficient than standard recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm going through the Learn You a Haskell book right now and I'm curious about how this particular example works.  The book first demonstrates an implementation of `findKey` using traditional recursion:

```
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v  
findKey key [] = Nothing  
findKey key ((k,v):xs) = if key == k  
                            then Just v  
                            else findKey key xs
```

The book then follows up with a shorter implementation using `foldr`

```
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v  
findKey key = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> if key == k then Just v else acc) Nothing
```

With the standard recursion, the function should immediately return once it hits the first element with the provided key.  If I understand the `foldr` implementation correctly, it will iterate over the entire list every time, even if it matched the first element it came across.  That doesn't seem like a very efficient way to handle the problem.

Is there something I'm not getting about how the `foldr` implementation works?  Or is there some kind of magic within Haskell that makes this implementation not quite as inefficient as I think it is?

Comment: Note: the compiler isn't able to use any property of your generic recursive definition. However the compiler knows how to treat `foldr` via rewriting rules, which means that defining functions via `foldr` allows the compiler to optimize the code more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `foldr` is written using standard recursion.
2. The recursive call to `foldr` is hidden inside of `acc`. If your code doesn't use `acc`, it will never be computed (because Haskell is lazy). So the `foldr` version is efficient and will also return early.

Here's an example demonstrating this:

```
Prelude> foldr (\x z -> "done") "acc" [0 ..]
"done"
```

This expression returns `"done"` immediately, even though the input list is infinitely long.

---

If `foldr` is defined as:

```
foldr f z (x : xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
foldr _ z [] = z
```

, then evaluation goes via

```
f x (foldr f z xs)
    where
    f = \x z -> "done"
    x = 0
    z = "acc"
    xs = ...  -- unevaluated, but is [1 ..]
```

which is

```
(\x z -> "done") 0 (foldr (\x z -> "done") "acc" [1 ..])
```

which turns into `"done"` because the first function doesn't use `z`, so the recursive call is never needed.

Comment: I'll need to keep staring at this for awhile until it sinks in, but I think I get what you mean about the recursion being built into `acc`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> If I understand the foldr implementation correctly, it will iterate over the entire list every time, even if it matched the first element it came across.

This is wrong. `foldr` will evaluate the list only as much as needed.

E.g.

```
foldr (&&) True [True, False, error "unreached code here"]
```

returns `False` since the error is never evaluated, precisely as in

```
(True && (False && (error "unreached code here" && True)))
```

Indeed, since the end of the list is never reached, we can also write

```
foldr (&&) (error "end") [True, False, error "unreached code here"]
```

and still obtain `False`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code which demonstrates that `foldr` does indeed "short-circuit" the evaluation of `findKey`:

```
import Debug.Trace

findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v  
findKey key = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> if key == k then Just v else acc) Nothing  

tr x = trace msg x
  where msg = "=== at: " ++ show x

thelist = [ tr (1,'a'), tr (2,'b'), tr (3, 'c'), tr (4, 'd') ]
```

An example of running `findKey` in ghci:

```
*Main> findKey 2 thelist
=== at: (1,'a')
=== at: (2,'b')
Just 'b'
*Main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of foldr using the following definition (using standard recursion):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f e [] = e
foldr f e (x:xs) = f x (foldr f e xs)
```

The third line shows that the second implementation for findKey will return upon finding the first match.

---

As a sidenote: assume you had the following definition (which does not have identical functionality) for findKey (as an exercise you might want to rewrite the definition using foldr):

```
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> [v]
findKey key [] = []
findKey key ((kHead, vHead):rest) = if (key == kHead) then vHead:(findKey key rest) else findKey key rest
```

Now you might think that this would iterate through the whole input list. Depending on how you invoke this function, it could be the case that it iterates through the whole list, but at the same time this can give you the first match efficiently too. Due to Haskell's lazy evaluation the following code:

```
head (findKey key li)
```

will give you the first match (assuming that there's one) with the same efficiency as your first example.

Answer (score 2):

```
foldr f z [a,b,c,...,n]                   == 
a `f` (b `f` (c `f` (... (n `f` z) ...))) == 
f a (foldr f z [b,c,...,n])               == 
f a acc   where   acc = foldr f z [b,c,...,n]
```

So *if* your `f` returns *before* [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) `acc`, `acc` remains not forced, i.e. no part of the list argument beyond its head element `a` is accessed, like e.g. when you have

```
f a acc = ...
```

If, on the other hand, your `f` does force its second argument, e.g. if it's defined as

```
f a (x:xs) = ...
```

then the `acc` *is* forced before `f` starts its work, and the list *will* be accessed in whole before the processing begins -- in whole, because `acc = f b acc2` and *that* invocation of `f` must force *its* second argument, `acc2`, so its value, `acc`, can be forced (pattern-matched with `(x:xs)`, that is); and so forth.